# Concatenate rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables.

```
CREATE TABLE `cms_compound` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nomenclature` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `version_number` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `version_region_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `cms_compound_disease` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `compound_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `disease_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `cms_disease` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `acronym` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `version_number` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `version_region_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `cms_version_region` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `version_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `region_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

And i am using the following query,

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
    c.id, 
    c.nomenclature, 
    d.acronym
FROM 
    compound c 
LEFT JOIN 
    compound_disease cd ON (cd.compound_id = c.id) 
LEFT JOIN 
    disease d ON (cd.disease_id = d.id) 
LEFT JOIN 
    version_region vr ON (vr.id = c.version_region_id) 
WHERE 
    c.version_number = 2 AND vr.version_id = 2 AND vr.region_id = 1 
LIMIT 0, 10
```

this gives me following result.

```
+-----+--------------+---------+
| id  | nomenclature | acronym |
+-----+--------------+---------+
| 155 | AEB071       | ALL     |
| 155 | AEB071       | AML     |
| 155 | AEB071       | AdCC    |
| 156 | Nilotinib    | NULL    |
| 161 | Buparlisib   | NULL    |
| 162 | BYL719       | NULL    |
+-----+--------------+---------+
```

Notice that id `155` for nomenclature `AEB071` are repeated after the `LEFT JOIN`.

I want the following result (acronym concatenation)

```
+-----+--------------+--------------------+
| id  | nomenclature | acronym            |
+-----+--------------+--------------------+
| 155 | AEB071       | ALL, AML, AdCC     |
| 156 | Nilotinib    | NULL               |
| 161 | Buparlisib   | NULL               |
| 162 | BYL719       | NULL               |
+-----+--------------+--------------------+
```

How can i do this using MySQL query ?

Comment: [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) is the active ingredient to get the result you are looking for.

Comment: My preference is to handle this kind of thing in the application level code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 
    c.id, 
    c.nomenclature, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(d.acronym) 
FROM 
    compound c 
LEFT JOIN 
    compound_disease cd ON (cd.compound_id = c.id) 
LEFT JOIN 
    disease d ON (cd.disease_id = d.id) 
LEFT JOIN 
    version_region vr ON (vr.id = c.version_region_id) 
WHERE 
    c.version_number = 2 AND vr.version_id = 2 AND vr.region_id = 1 
GROUP BY
  c.id,
  c.nomenclature
```

Comment: This gives me issue when i want to implement LIKE for that record.

Comment: LIKE for which record? Which issue?

Comment: It was coming from the limitation of the query the script was generating, it is solved, thanks Alma